# Filter products by category with AJAX problem with displaying products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have problem with displaying products from category with ajax.
I've rendered all categories and all products on page and my categories are links and I prevented default action on links and I want to achieve this. When you click on the link of the category, that triggers ajax and show bellow products from that category, everything happens on same page without reload. But all I got is "no post found" when i click on category link

```
function ajax_filter_get_posts( $taxonomy ) {

    // Verify nonce
    if( !isset( $_POST['afp_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['afp_nonce'], 'afp_nonce' ) )
      die('Permission denied');

    $taxonomy = $_POST['taxonomy'];

    // WP Query
    $args = array(
      'tag' => $taxonomy,
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'posts_per_page' => 10

    );


    if( !$taxonomy ) {
      unset( $args['tag'] );
    }

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

      $output  = '<h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'. get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
      $output .= get_the_excerpt();

      $result = 'success';

    endwhile; else:
      $output = '<h2>No posts found</h2>';
      $result = 'fail';

    endif;

    $response = json_encode($output);
    echo $response;

    die();
  }

  add_action('wp_ajax_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
```

```
<article>
<?php
/**
 * Template name: AJAX Post Filter by Taxonomy
 *
 */
get_header();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$tax = 'product_cat';
$terms = get_terms( $tax );
$count = count( $terms );

if ( $count > 0 ): ?>
    <div class="post-tags">
    <?php
        echo '<div class="container">';
        echo '<div class="row">';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
         $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $tax );

         echo '<div class="col-4">';
        echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '" class="tax-filter" title="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a> ';
        echo '</div>';

     }
     echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
     ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;

if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
<div class="tagged-posts">
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <h2><a class="<?php echo $term->name; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<?php else: ?>
    <div class="tagged-posts">
        <h2>No posts found</h2>
    </div>
<?php endif;  ?>

</article>
<?php
get_footer();
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.tax-filter').click( function(event) {


        if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }

        var selecetd_taxonomy = $(this).attr('title');

        $('.tagged-posts').fadeOut();

        data = {
            action: 'filter_posts',
            afp_nonce: afp_vars.afp_nonce,
            taxonomy: selecetd_taxonomy,
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'product',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
            data: data,
            success: function( data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest ) {
                $('.tagged-posts').html( data );
                $('.tagged-posts').fadeIn();
                console.log( textStatus );
                console.log( XMLHttpRequest );
            },
            error: function( MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log( MLHttpRequest );
                console.log( textStatus );
                console.log( errorThrown );
                $('.tagged-posts').html( 'No posts found' );
                $('.tagged-posts').fadeIn();
            }
        })

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query args you are filtering by `tag` whereas the taxonomy term that you're passing in is actually a `product_cat`.

Try changing your query arguments in `ajax_filter_get_posts` to the following:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => 10
  'tax_query' => array(
    array (
      'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $taxonomy,
    )
  ),
);
```

Comment: I've tried but nothing... works with post_type post but not with product

Comment: Ok, pick a product category that you know has some products. Try putting the slug for that term into the query (ie. `'apples'` instead of `$taxonomy`) to see if it works

Comment: it works, but when I try to click on that category ajax returns nothing

Comment: Ok so you've confirmed that your query is set up correctly and that there are matching posts in the database.

My advice is that you should ensure that every other piece is working as expected:

1. Is the jQuery retrieving the category slug as expected? 
2. Is the category slug being passed to the ajax handler as expected? 
3. Is the category slug being passed into the query as expected?

You will eventually uncover the error if you check each step *without* assuming that it's working as expected